# Servlet-API bundle not providing JavaServlet capability - felix.http.jetty cannot run

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-http-service

I am trying to get the org.apache.felix.http.jetty bundle working to provide a HTTP Service to my OSGi environment.

I also have the servlet-api bundle deployed, which exports the versioned packages, but does not provide the JavaServlet capability (as it probably should, based on the [OSGi Alliance](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/ReferenceContract) page on Reference Contracts).

Here's part of the MANIFEST of the servlet-api bundle

```
Export-Package: javax.servlet;uses:="javax.servlet.descriptor,javax.se
 rvlet.annotation";version="3.1.0",javax.servlet.descriptor;version="3
 .1.0",javax.servlet.annotation;uses:="javax.servlet";version="3.1.0",
 javax.servlet.http;uses:="javax.servlet";version="3.1.0"
Implementation-Version: 3.1.0
Specification-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Bundle-Name: Java Servlet API
Bundle-Vendor: GlassFish Community
Import-Package: javax.servlet;version="3.1.0",javax.servlet.annotation
 ;version="3.1.0",javax.servlet.descriptor;version="3.1.0",javax.servl
 et.http;version="3.1.0"
```

The `Provide-Capability` header is not specified at all.

So, when I start the OSGi container, it complains with this error:

```
 Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.felix.http.jetty [28](R 28.0)]
  osgi.contract; (&(osgi.contract=JavaServlet)(version=3.1))]
```

Anyone knows how this can be fixed?

Comment: Got it working by creating a fragment-bundle that makes the servlet-api bundle provide the JavaServlet capability. But this is hacky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using [`org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api%22) bundle from Felix itself.